# Gauss-Newton Wrong Calculations on Python

Tags: python, math

i am making a Gauss Newton algorithm on Python but i think my answer is wrong somehow. On first iteration is returns true values but other iterations are wrong i think. On wikipedia page they gave a example question but my code shows wrong values on that. I tried [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699057/implementation-of-the-gauss-newton-method-from-wikipedia-example/29701707) but it's not worked for me. Is there a mistake on my code? I don't get it and i couldn't solve this problem few 2 days.

My Teacher's question:

```
x = [0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25]
y = [0.28, 0.57, 0.68, 0.74, 0.79]
inial values a0 = 1, a1 = 1
f(x) = a0*(1–e^(–a1*x))
df/da0 = 1–e^(–a1*x)
df/da1 = a0*x*(1–e^(–a1x))
```

This is my code solves that problem (i think):

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import math
import scipy.misc
from  math import e


def GaussNewtonMethod(startpoints):
    x = np.array([0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25])
    y = np.array([0.28, 0.57, 0.68, 0.74, 0.79])
    CalculatedPoints = startpoints
    for k in range(5):
        # Calculate Z
        Z = []
        for i in range(len(x)):
            Z.append([1-pow(e,-CalculatedPoints[1]*x[i]),CalculatedPoints[0]*x[i]*pow(e,-CalculatedPoints[1]*x[i])])
        D = []
        for i in range(len(y)):
            D.append(y[i]-Z[i][0]);
        D = np.array(D)
        Z = np.array(Z)
        ZT = Z.transpose()
        eq1 = ZT.dot(Z)
        eq2 = inv(eq1)
        eq3 = eq2.dot(ZT)
        eq4 = eq3.dot(D)
        CalculatedPoints = np.add(startpoints,eq4)
        print('new startpoints',CalculatedPoints)

    newy = []
    for i in x:
        newy.append(CalculatedPoints[0]*(1-pow(e,-i*CalculatedPoints[1])))
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    axs.scatter(x, y)
    axs.plot(x, newy)
    fig.suptitle('Gauss - Newton')
    plt.show()


GaussNewtonMethod([1,1])
```

My answer:

```
new startpoints [0.72852264 1.50193087] // this the true one
new startpoints [0.7910431  1.17577025]
new startpoints [0.76868865 1.46238863]
new startpoints [0.79016327 1.20404379]
new startpoints [0.77254469 1.43636334]
```

for more information about my calculations
[image: Screenshot]

The question's graph:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you may have the derivatives wrong. I get df/da0 = (1–e^(–a1*x)) df/da1 = a0*x*(e^(–a1x))

Comment: Isn't it like that already? a0 is CalculatedPoints[0] and a1 is CalculatedPoints[1]. I can't see any mistake. I droped a screenshot below the question.

Comment: I was going by what was in the first code block in your question; typos perthaps